# Giving Error "TypeError: value is not a functionDetails"

Tags: google-apps-script

```
functionfillvaluedown() 
     var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
      var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("User Form"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form   
      var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Database"); //delcare a variable and set with the Database 
      var currentRange = datasheet.getRange("b2:b" + datasheet.getLastRow())
    var newRange = []
    var NewFillValue 
    currentRange.getValues().map(function(value) {
      if (value[0] !==''){
        NewFillValue = value(0)
        newRange.push([NewFillValue])
      } else {
        newRange.push([NewFillValue])
      }
      })
      currentRange.setValue(newRange)
    }
```

Comment: May be typo? `value(0)` should be `value[0]`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.